# How does "set mouse=a" actually work?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, mouse

Could somebody explain, what is the reason to use `set mouse=a`? People say that thus I will be able, for example, to resize split windows (`:sp`, `:vsp`) by dragging separators, but I already can do it if I simply start Vim in `cmd.exe` on Windows, even if I start Vim without any settings (`cmd.exe`, then `vim -u NONE`). So why may I need `set mouse=a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `vim -Nu NONE` in `cmd.exe` you have `mouse=a` and that is why you can change split sizes with your mouse. Try to `set mouse=` and resize a split, it wouldn't work.

On my linux box `mouse` is empty by default so I can't resize splits with a mouse.

Help topic `:h 'mouse'` tells exactly this:

```
'mouse'         string  (default "", "a" for GUI and Win32,
                    set to "a" or "nvi" in |defaults.vim|)
```

So the reason to `set mouse=a` is obvious... to be able to use mouse in vim.